# How to build an ARM (Linaro) image in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, arm, linaro

I am trying to build a Linaro image following this blog:

http://fullshovel.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/new-life-into-a-linaro-based-server-image/

(I have also tried to follow the instructions in:
https://wiki.linaro.org/Platform/DevPlatform/CrossCompile/LiveBuild)

I am getting the following output:

```
lb build --verbose
[2014-03-10 22:55:37] lb_build --verbose
[2014-03-10 22:55:37] lb_bootstrap --verbose
P: Setting up cleanup function
[2014-03-10 22:55:37] lb_bootstrap_cache restore --verbose
W: skipping /usr/lib/live/build/lb_bootstrap_cache, foreign architecture(s).
[2014-03-10 22:55:37] lb_bootstrap_copy --verbose
[2014-03-10 22:55:37] lb_bootstrap_cdebootstrap --verbose
[2014-03-10 22:55:37] lb_bootstrap_debootstrap --verbose
[2014-03-10 22:55:37] lb_bootstrap_cache save --verbose
W: skipping /usr/lib/live/build/lb_bootstrap_cache, foreign architecture(s).
P: Begin unmounting filesystems...
P: Saving caches...
[2014-03-10 22:55:38] lb_chroot --verbose
P: Setting up cleanup function
[2014-03-10 22:55:38] lb_chroot_cache restore --verbose
[2014-03-10 22:55:38] lb_chroot_devpts install --verbose
[2014-03-10 22:55:38] lb_testroot 
E: lb_chroot_devpts: one of .build/config .build/bootstrap is missing
P: Begin unmounting filesystems...
P: Saving caches...
```

I there is no `.build` directory in the directory where I execute `lb build`. What is going on? I tried using `--verbose` and `--debug` but `lb` does not give any more information about why it fails.

What dependency do I have to install for this to work?

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and lb version 3.0~a57-1.